# Add day to current date and show in textbox?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to show my due date based on the number of days the user enters but it does not work, does not

```js
function calcDays() {
  var todaydate = new Date();
  var day = todaydate.getDate();
  var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
  var data_entrada = day + " / " + month + " / " + year;
  var data_permanecia = document.getElementById('data_permanecia');
  var data_saida.setDate(data_entrada + data_permanecia);
  document.getElementById("data_entrada").value = data_entrada;
  document.getElementById("data_saida").value = data_saida;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="data_permanencia">Data de permanecia</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data_permanecia" id="data_permanecia" placeholder="Dias">
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="inputCity">Data de entrada</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_entrada" name="data_entrada">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="data_saida">Data de saida prevista</label>
    <input type="text" id="data_saida" class="form-control" onclick="calcDays()" name="data_saida" value="">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Made you a snippet. It has console errors `var data_saida.setDate(data_entrada + data_permanecia);` is not valid JS. Also you forgot .value here: `var data_permanecia = document.getElementById('data_permanecia')`

Comment: You are using `setDate()` incorrectly. It does not accept the string `5/4/2020[object HTMLLabelElement]`, which is what you passing in your code. So please fix grabbing the amount of days to add and use the correct syntax for `setDate()`.

Comment: ` 
 function calcule(){ 
 var todaydate = new Date();
 var day = todaydate.getDate();
 var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
 var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
 var data_entrada = day + " / " + month + " / " + year;
 var data_permanecia = document.getElementById ('data_permanecia');
 var data_saida = (new Date() + data_permanecia); 
 document.getElementById("data_entrada").value = data_entrada; 
 document.getElementById("data_saida").value = data_saida;  
`


And now its giving me wrong time

Answer (score 0):

It will run only on the first load and the textbox is still empty.
I suggest using input events and perform date calculations when user inputs a text.

```
{
  var todaydate = new Date();
  var day = todaydate.getDate();
  var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
  var data_entrada = day + " / " + month + " / " + year;
  document.getElementById("data_entrada").value = data_entrada; 

  function setSaida(startDate,days){
   /* you might need a start date validation here... */
    var date=new Date();
    date.setDate(startDate.getDate()  + days);
    if(!isNaN(date)){
      document.getElementById("data_saida").value=date.getDate()+" / "+date.getMonth()+" / "+date.getFullYear();
    }
  }
  //listen to user's input
  const $source = document.querySelector('#data_permanecia');
  const typeHandler=function(e){
    setSaida(todaydate,e.target.value);
  }
  $source.addEventListener('input', typeHandler)
  $source.addEventListener('propertychange', typeHandler)
}
```

Comment: It works but its adding some other value to the date

Comment: https://codepen.io/Sderdev/pen/NWqazLM?editors=1010

Please check this link